# Error al crear thread en c++

Tags: c++, hilos

Estoy tratando de crear un hilo en c++, pero mi código no compila.

```
void Programa::ordenUnoParelelismo()
{
    std::cout << "<<-- ALGORITMO UNO PARALELISMO -->>" << std::endl;
    int hilos = intInput("Ingrese numero de hilos: ");
    std::vector<std::thread> vt; //Contiene los hilos
    bool posible = this->cantidad / hilos >= 2;
    while(!posible) {
        std::cout << "No es posible ordenar el vector con tantos hilos." << std::endl;
        hilos = intInput("Ingrese numero de hilos: ");
    }
    std::cout << "Hilos: " << hilos << std::endl;
    //Quicksort Paralelismo
    int separacion = ceil((double)this->cantidad / hilos);
    int inicio = 0;
    int fin = (inicio + separacion) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < hilos; i++) {
        if (fin >= this->cantidad) {
            fin = this->cantidad-1;
        }
        std::thread hilo(&quickSortParalelismo, this->vectorOriginal, inicio, fin);
        vt.push_back(hilo);
        inicio = fin + 1;
        fin = (inicio + separacion) - 1;
    }
}

void Programa::quickSortParalelismo(int * arr, int inicio, int fin)
{
    int pivote = arr[fin];
}
```

Este es el error que sale:

```
error C2276: '&': operación no válida de la expresión de función miembro enlazada
```

Y es en esta linea:

```
std::thread hilo(&quickSortParalelismo, this->vectorOriginal, inicio, fin);
```

Por favor, limítense a resolver mi duda de por qué aparece el error. Si el algoritmo de QuickSort está malo, es mi trabajo resolverlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda?

Answer (score 4):

Necesitas pasar el puntero `this` como primer parametro de tu metodo, estamos hablando de metodos no estaticos, entonces considera este ejemplo:

```
class test
{
    public:
        int MyMember;

        void MyMethodA(int a);  
        void InitThread();  
};

void test::MyMethodA(int a)
{
    std::cout << "V: " << a << std::endl;
}

void test::InitThread()
{
    std::thread tx(&test::MyMethodA, this, this->MyMember);
    tx.join();
}

int main()
{
   test ins;
   ins.InitThread();

   return 0;
}
```

El puntero `this` es usado en cada uno de los metodos de una clase para la referencia de la instancia actual...

Comment: Hola, entiendo apenas tu respueta, soy principiante en C++. Tengo que pasarle (en el thread) la funcion con &, luego this, y luego, los parámetros de la función?

Comment: Intenté pasarle como primer parámetro 'this', pero aún no funciona, da el mismo error.

Comment: @Juanky Para funciones miembro no-estáticas, tienes que *cualificar* completamente el nombre de la función: `std::thread hilo( &Programa::quickSortParalelismo, this, this->vectorOriginal, inicio, fin );`. Es un detalle que se le *escapó* a @nikomaster ;-)

Comment: @Trauma Si, probablemente en visual C++, ya lo he editado, en gcc al menos compila perfecto y no es necesario hacer eso... pero también compila con gcc...

Comment: @Juanky leé la documentación acerca del uso de `std::thread` y sus argumentos en el constructor, de otra forma no entederás...

Answer (score 3):

Alternativamente a la [respuesta de @nikomaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/123457/19610), y por lo que se ve en tu código, puedes declarar tu función `quickSortParalelismo( )` como `static`.

Esta solución solo es válida sin **no utilizas ninguna variable-miembro no-estática** en el código de la función.

```
class Programa {
public:
  static void quickSortParalelismo( int *, int, int );
  ...
};
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con **variable-miembro no-estática** ?

Comment: A que, desde dentro de tu función `quickSortParalelismo( )`, no accedas a ninguna variable de tu clase.

Answer (score 3):

> Estoy tratando de crear un hilo en c++, pero mi código no compila.

La utilidad [`std::thread`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) se crea facilitando un [funtor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funtor) o una función, el parámetro facilitado será ejecutado en paralelo al hilo principal.

En tu caso estás creando un `std::thread` sobre una función. En el caso de crear un hilo sobre una función se espera que el programador provea un puntero a función. Por desgracia te falla porque  no has tenido en cuenta (o no sabes) que en C++ existen dos familias de funciones:

#### Funciones *libres*.

En esta categoría de funciones entrarían todas las funciones que no están asociadas a ningún objeto, es decir, las funciones que puedan ser llamadas por su nombre sin anteponer una instancia de objeto, éstos son ejemplos de funciones libres:

- [`std::pow`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).
- [`std::swap`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).
- [`std::copy`, `std::copy_if`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Las funciones libres tienen la peculiaridad que su nombre es implícitamente convertible a puntero<sup>1</sup>, así que si tenemos un tipo `T` que es puntero a una función que no devuelve nada y recibe un puntero a entero y dos enteros `using T = void(*)(int *, int, int)` podemos usar `T` para crear punteros a funciones con esa firma y podremos asignarles directamente el nombre de la función:

```
void klatu(int *, int, int) {}
void barada(int *, int, int) {}
void nikto(int *, int, int) {}
void alakhazam() {}

T p_k = klatu;  // Correcto, se convierte implicitamente a puntero
T p_b = barada; // Correcto, se convierte implicitamente a puntero
T p_n = &nikto; // Correcto, puntero a la funcion nikto
T p_a = alakhazam; // Error, alakhazam no es convertible a void(*)(int *, int, int)
```

Como puedes ver el [operador dirección-de](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) puede también usarse en funciones libres aunque el nombre de la función sea convertible de manera implícita a puntero del tipo de la función.

Para usar los punteros como si fueran las funciones a las que apuntan, basta con poner el nombre del puntero y pasar los parámetros entre paréntesis:

```
p_k(nullptr, 0, 0); // llama a klatu
p_b(nullptr, 0, 0); // llama a barada
p_n(nullptr, 0, 0); // llama a nikto
```

#### Funciones miembro.

En esta categoría de funciones entrarían las funciones que están asociadas a un objeto, es decir, las funciones que necesitan de una instancia de objeto para ser llamadas, éstos son ejemplos de funciones miembro:

- [`std::string::copy`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy).
- [`std::vector::reserve`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).
- [`std::thread::join`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Las funciones miembro requieren una instancia de objeto para ser llamadas porque en el interior de dichas funciones es posible usar variables miembro del objeto, si no tenemos objeto asociado ¿Cómo accedemos a dichas variables miembro? es por este motivo que las funciones miembro tienen un parámetro *oculto* que es `this` y por el mismo motivo para referirnos a ellas debemos anteponer también el tipo del objeto al que pertenecen.

A diferencia de las funciones libres, las funciones miembro **requieren** el operador dirección-de para obtener un puntero a ellas, así que si tenemos un tipo `T` que es puntero a una función miembro de una clase `Programa` y dicha función no devuelve nada mientras que recibe un puntero a entero y dos enteros `using T = void(Programa::*)(int *, int, int)` podemos usar `T` para crear punteros a funciones de esa clase con esa firma si usamos el operador `&`:

```
struct Programa
{
    void Programa::ordenUnoParelelismo()
    {
        T f = &Programa::quickSortParalelismo; // Correcto
        T g = Programa::quickSortParalelismo;  // Error, falta '&'
        T h = &quickSortParalelismo;  // error C2276, falta el nombre de la clase
        T i = quickSortParalelismo;  // Error, falta el nombre de la clase y '&'
    }

    quickSortParalelismo(int *, int, int) {}
};
```

Para usar los punteros a funciones miembro como si fueran las funciones a las que apuntan, hay que pasar tanto una instancia de objeto como los parámetros:

```
struct S
{
    void f(int parametro) { std::cout << valor << ' ' << parametro << '\n'; }
    int valor{};
} uno{1}, dos{2};

using T = void(S::*)(int);
// puntero apunta a cualquier funcion de 'S' que devuelva 'void' y reciba 'int'
T puntero = &S::f;

/*        Llamamos la funcion apuntada por 'puntero' sobre la instancia
 vvv <--- 'uno' pasando como parametro '1' */
(uno.*puntero)(1);
/*        Llamamos la funcion apuntada por 'puntero' sobre la instancia
 vvv <--- 'dos' pasando como parametro '2' */
(dos.*puntero)(2);
```

Puedes ver el código de este ejemplo funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XmmTlCahT3KkVQTV)</kbd>.

#### Tu problema.

Has acertado en que el primer parámetro del constructor de un `std::thread` es la función a ejecutar y los siguientes parámetros del constructor serán los parámetros de la función:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Pero como hemos visto en el apartado de *Funciones miembro* te falta el nombre de la clase para que el compilador entienda que te estás refiriendo a una función miembro:

```
std::thread hilo(&Programa::quickSortParalelismo, this->vectorOriginal, inicio, fin);
//                ~~~~~~~~ <-- Requiere el nombre de la clase propietaria de la funcion
```

Pero este código también falla, eso es porque estamos trabajando con una función miembro y necesitará también una instancia de objeto para ejecutar dicha función:

```
std::thread hilo(&Programa::quickSortParalelismo, *this, this->vectorOriginal, inicio, fin);
//          Requiere una instancia de objeto ---> ~~~~~
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Parecido, aunque para nada igual, a lo que sucede con los arreglos (`int arreglo[10]`) en que el nombre del arreglo es el puntero al primer elemento de dicho arreglo.